# Why does Swift need these similar functions? Is it kind of redundant?

Tags: swift

There are some similar methods in Swift. They look similar, actually their functions are also similar. They are:

`popFirst()`, `popLast()`, `dropFirst()`, `dropLast()`, `removeFirst()`, `removeLast()`

Especially `popFirst()` and `removeFirst()`, according to **[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection)**:

> **func popFirst()**
>
> Removes and returns the first element of the collection.
>
> **func removeFirst()**
>
> Removes and returns the first element of the collection.

Their document descriptions are totally same. Actually I tried a lot (a whole page in playground) to see whether there are some significant differences between these methods. The answer is *there are some **very small** differences* between **some methods**, and **some methods are totally the same** according to my test.

Some methods, `popFirst()`, `popLast()` and `dropLast()`, `dropFirst()` are different when used on **String** and **Array**. But according to my test, they all can be replaced by `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()` (despite there are some tiny differences).

So my question is why Swift has to keep these similar methods. Is it kind of redundant?

Comment: You note that "(despite there are some tiny differences)." Aren't those differences exactly this point of having different methods? Which ones are "totally the same?" `popFirst()`, `removeFirst()`, and `dropFirst()` definitely all have different behaviors (and in fact, different signatures, so you don't need to test in Playgrounds, since they're obviously different).

Comment: @RobNapier If those tiny differences are the value of those methods' existence, I would say "Ok, fine." But....I actually just want to know more about the basic knowledges of Swift, I don't think my question worth downVote. After all I use question mark in my question title, not like *"It is redundant!!"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Apple did not make it easy to find, it does mention that `pop` returns `nil` for an empty collection, and that `remove` throws an error when there is nothing to remove.

However, you should be able to tell the same from the signatures of these functions:

- `popFirst` returns an optional, which implies that you can pop first element even from an empty collection
- `removeFirst`, on the other hand, is not optional. Signatures like that imply that it is an error to call this method in a state when it cannot return a value.

This could be easily confirmed using a playground:

```
var test1 = Set<String>(["a", "b"])
let x1 = test1.popFirst()
let y1 = test1.popFirst()
let z1 = test1.popFirst()            // returns nil
var test2 = Set<String>(["a", "b"])
let x2 = test2.removeFirst()
let y2 = test2.removeFirst()
let z2 = test2.removeFirst()         // Throws an error
```

Comment: FYI, the documentation does mention this in the "Return Value" section. You can also Command+Click a method in Xcode to see the "header" with full documentation.

Comment: @ThanhPham You are right, when I click into the doc I see both effects mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I looked through the doc of all those methods many times by *option+click* or *command+click*. I am not new to Swift, I just want to know if it is necessary to keep all those methods in Swift. Now I know, those tiny differences seem very important to all of you. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Apart from returning optional and non-optional values, the difference between `popFirst()` and `removeFirst()` is better explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323292. `popFirst()` only works if the collection is its own subsequence type. So it won't work on an `Int` array defined as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. But `removeFirst()` will work here.

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.8.1

**dropFirst**: returns a subsequence where the first k items are removed, leaving the underlying array unchanged.

**removeFirst**: mutates the array, while returning the first k removed items

ex:

```
let arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arrayA.dropFirst()  // 2, 3, 4
print(arrayA)       // 1, 2, 3, 4

var arrayB = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arrayB.removeFirst()    // 1
print(arrayB)           // 2, 3, 4
```