# Why popFirst throws an error, but removeFirst works?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, immutability

```
struct Queue<T>{

    private var elements : [T] = []

    public mutating func enqueue(_ element: T){
        elements.append(element)
    }
    public mutating func dequeue() -> T?{
        return elements.popFirst()  // ERROR!
    }
    public mutating func dequeue2() -> T?{
        return elements.removeFirst()
    }
}
```

The error I get for `popFirst` is:

> cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is
>   immutable

Both [`popFirst`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice/1687956-popfirst) and [`removeFirst`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2884646-removefirst) are marked as `mutating` and both return and `T?`. So why isn't it working?

**EDIT:**  As others have commented, it seems to be some sort of bug. It's been discussed in the forums [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-4-cannot-use-mutating-member-on-immutable-value-self-is-immutable/6642).

**EDIT:** Still happens in Xcode 9.4.1 (Swift 4.1.2)

Comment: FYI - `removeFirst` returns `T`, not `T?`.

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Even `var a = [1,2,3]; let first = a.popFirst()` gives the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that particular error, but the link you sent for `popFirst` is for `ArraySlice`, not `Array`. If you create an `ArraySlice`, it works fine, e.g. `var a = ArraySlice(elements); let foo = a.popFirst()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is improved in Swift 4.2:

```
error: ios.playground:4:25: error: '[T]' requires the types '[T]' and 'ArraySlice<T>' be equivalent to use 'popFirst'
        return elements.popFirst()  // ERROR!
                        ^
```

You get the error because `popFirst` is not defined for all `Collection`s. It's only defined if the `Collection` is its own `SubSequence` type. [Here's the implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift):

```
extension Collection where SubSequence == Self {
  /// Removes and returns the first element of the collection.
  ///
  /// - Returns: The first element of the collection if the collection is
  ///   not empty; otherwise, `nil`.
  ///
  /// - Complexity: O(1)
  @inlinable
  public mutating func popFirst() -> Element? {
    // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
    guard !isEmpty else { return nil }
    let element = first!
    self = self[index(after: startIndex)..<endIndex]
    return element
  }
}
```

The extension requires `SubSequence == Self`. `Self` (with a capital S) is the type of `self` (with a lower-case s). It is the type on which you're calling `popFirst`. In your code, `Self` is `Array<T>`, also spelled `[T]`.

The constraint is necessary for this line of `popFirst` to compile:

> ```
> self = self[index(after: startIndex)..<endIndex]
>
> ^__^   ^_______________________________________^
>  |                         |
>  |                        This is a SubSequence.
>  |
> This is a Self.
> ```

`self[index(after: startIndex)..<endIndex]` is a `SubSequence`.

Swift can only assign a `SubSequence` to `Self` if it knows that `Self == SubSequence`.

`Array`'s `SubSequence` type is `ArraySlice`. Since `ArraySlice` is not the same type as `Array`, this extension doesn't apply to `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the extension you're probably looking for:

```
extension Array {
    @inlinable
    public mutating func popFirst() -> Element? {
        if isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            return removeFirst()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should extend RangeReplaceableCollection instead of Array `extension RangeReplaceableCollection  {` `@inlinable`
`public mutating func popFirst() -> Element? {` `guard !isEmpty else {` `return nil` `}`
    return removeFirst()
  }
}`